# What is the difference between $variable and %$variable%?

Tags: php, mysql

I have this piece of code here:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM example WHERE text LIKE '%$value%'");
```

Would it make a difference if I would use:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM example WHERE text LIKE '$value'");
```

If yes, what would it be? What would be the difference?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes this has nothing to do with php, its a sql thing, % means like a wildcard there could be 0 or more characters instead of it.

```
%abc% matches abc, aabca, aabc, abcd
%abc matches dabc, abc but not abcd or tabcd
abc% matches abcd, abc but not dabc, tabcd
```

Answer (score 12):

Its not a difference in PHP, its a wildcard in SQL. You can read more about it [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like). Essentially, %

> Matches any number of characters, even zero characters

Answer (score 2):

The difference is that '%$value%' will seach for matches containing $value (for exemple if $value = 'foo' it could return 'foobar' or 'barfoobar'), '$value' only matches the exact value of $value.

Answer (score 1):

In PHP there is no difference (although you might want to take a look at using PDO for your database queries), the '%' symbols affect the query executed in MySQL.

% acts as a wildcard so the first result will return anything that **contains** the term 'value' in its text attribute, whereas the second will return only records that match **exactly** the term 'value'